# Busybox: emulate line editing for read shell's built-in

Tags: shell, busybox, ash

I need to develop a simple text interface for an embedded system with more or less only the Busybox installed on it.

For my purposes the `read` shell built-in would have sufficed. But the Busybox `ash` (or any other shell, they use the same code for the built-in) does not support line editing or initial text in the `read` built-in.

Does anybody knows of a way in Busybox's `ash` to emulate `bash`'s `read -e -i <initial-text>` in a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

1. For `readline` emulation, there's `rlwrap` assuming it can be made to fit on the embedded system.  Invoke like so:  `rlwrap ash`, which provides command line history and editing.
2. For `read -e -i "foo" bar` emulation, try:

   ```
   read bar ; bar="foo$bar"
   ```